# How to Import New Data from MS Access Front End with SQL Server back end

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

- Hello,

I need to find a way to import new data into a database which comprises of a SQL Server back end and an MS Access 2010 front end with linked tables to the back end, from the front end.

Ideally, this would involve a user clicking a button on a form in the front end and selecting an excel spreadsheet with new data to import, which would then be saved in the back end SQL Server tables.

I have created a vba module in the Excel spreadsheet I want to import. The code is:

```
Public Function ExcelPicker(Optional strFileName As String, _
    Optional ByVal strWindowTitle As String = "Select an excel file") As String

    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    'Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .Title = strWindowTitle
        .Filters.Add "All files", "*.*", 1
        .Filters.Add "Excel Workbooks", "*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", 2
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            FilePicker = (.SelectedItems(1))
        Else
            FilePicker = vbNullString
        End If
    End With
    Set fd = Nothing
End Function
```

I have then created an import button on the MS Access 2010 front end, and in the OnClick event I have entered the code:

```
Private Sub cmdImportFilterResults_Click()

Dim sExcelFile As String
Set sExcelFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
'' if sExcelFile is not blank then
'' import the file to MSSQL linked table
If sExcelFile <> "" Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "[Database].Table_Result", sExcelFile, True
End If
End Sub
```

However, when I click on the import button in the front end, nothing is happening. What is wrong in my code or my solution?

Comment: This makes little sense. The _ExcelPicker_ function is stowed away in Excel, and your button in Access assigns an object to the string `sExcelFile`; this can't possible compile. You may have to rethink your concept.

Comment: You can move your first function into the Access front end and merge it with the second, to find the required workbook and then import it. Some code will need to be revised to suit the Access environment. This will create a table in the front end - to export that to the back end will require further coding.

Comment: Hi  user3728595 thanks this sounds good. Could you provide the code edits and examples for Access and give me more details of how exactly I'd add it to the front end?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```
Private Sub cmdImportFilterResults_Click()
    Dim strWindowTitle As String
    Dim objDialog As Object
    Dim sExcelFile As String

    strWindowTitle = "Select an excel file"
    Set objDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With objDialog
        .Title = strWindowTitle
        .Filters.Add "Excel Workbooks", "*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No File Selected."
        Else
            sExcelFile = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))
        End If
    End With
    ' if sExcelFile is not blank then
    ' import the file to MSSQL linked table
    If sExcelFile <> "" Then
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "[Database].Table_Result", sExcelFile, True
    End If
End Sub
```